# Баг связанный с NullReferenceException в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При написании скрипта для инвентаря, когда я запускаю сцену, начинает  появляться ошибка NullReferenceException из-за того, что "якобы" юнити не может вернуть спрайт предмета, и поэтому персонаж не может двигаться. Я думаю это баг, т.к при перезапуске скрипта на ItemAssets всё начинает работать и персонаж двигается (https://youtu.be/1Y6KPayRaRQ записал видео, чтобы понятно было). Я просто не понимаю, что делать, т.к это очень мешает.

Ошибка вылезает в этой части кода:

```
public Sprite GetSprite()
{
    switch (itemType)
    {
        default:
        case ItemType.Apple:
            return ItemAssets.Instance.AppleSprite;
        case ItemType.Bacon:
            return ItemAssets.Instance.BaconSprite;
        case ItemType.Bread:;
            return ItemAssets.Instance.BreadSprite;
        case ItemType.Fish:
            return ItemAssets.Instance.FishSprite;
        case ItemType.Steak:
            return ItemAssets.Instance.SteakSprite;
        case ItemType.Onion:
            return ItemAssets.Instance.OnionSprite;
    }
}
```

А это скрипт, который висит на объекте ItemAssets, и который приходится перезапускать:

```
public class ItemAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ItemAssets Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {   
    Instance = this;
    }

    public Transform pfItemWorld;

    public Sprite AppleSprite;
    public Sprite BaconSprite;
    public Sprite BreadSprite;
    public Sprite FishSprite;
    public Sprite SteakSprite;
    public Sprite OnionSprite;

}
```

UPD:.
[image: первый запуск с ошибкой запуск с ошибкой]
[image: запуск после рестарта скрипта]

Comment: Значит при вызове `GetSprite()` где-то `null`, например в `Instance`. И я бы на вашем месте не использовал бы такой метод, а например `Dictionary<ItemType, Sprite>` вместо него.

Comment: @aepot Ну так почему тогда после сброса скрипта с объекта всё становится хорошо?

Comment: Откуда же я знаю, я рассуждаю только на основе того кода, что вижу. Как и когда у вас вызывается `Awake()`, вы не показали. Вообще посмотрите, какие бывают правильные практики для реализации шаблона программирования **Singleton**. То что у вас - очень похоже на **Singleton**, но далеко от идеала. Хотя, я может просто плохо знаю `Mono`, это виднее тем, кто хорошо знает.

Comment: @aepot Сейчас попробовал запустить скрипт с `Debug.Log()`, и, по каким-то неизвестным мне причинам, `Awake()` запускается уже после `GetSprite()`. Дополнил вопрос скринами логов

Comment: Вот, уже вопрос ближе к пониманию проблемы. По поводу словаря все же подумайте. Представьте у вас будет не 6, а 236 спрайтов, вы под каждый будете отдельное поле добавлять? :) То же самое про энумератор, используйте словарь и строковый ключ.

Comment: @aepot Всё, я решил проблему, поставив скрипт ItemAssets выше по приоритету выполнения в Execution Order и ошибка пропала. Но на счёт словаря, не могли бы Вы мне привести пример как он должен инициализироваться с ItemType и Sprite; буду очень Вам благодарен. (Просто на C# не очень давно пересел :D )

Comment: это уже другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Comment: @aepot https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1182802/Как-сделать-словарь-для-инициализации-спрайтов

Answer (score -1):

можно написать `дебаг.лог()` и на `эвейке` и на `гетCпрайт`. И практически наверняка увидишь что при нуллРефЕксепшн гетспрайт вызывается ДО евейка.

aepot в коментариях все правильно написал - реализовать через перетаскивание спрайтов в инспектор это не очень хорошая практика. Это допустимо, но нежелательно ибо порождает много проблем. Например такие как здесь.

Но, даже, если настроить сейчас что бы все работало, во время разработки будет периодиески что-то отваливаться с таким подходом. Желательно спрайты/префабы доставать кодом из ассетов - тогда проблем будет значительно меньше.