# Как сделать словарь для инициализации спрайтов?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как переписать и использовать данный `GetSprite()` под `Dictionary<ItemType, Sprite>`, чтобы не использовать отдельное поле под каждый спрайт:

```
public Sprite GetSprite()
{
    switch (itemType)
    {
         default:
         case ItemType.Apple:
             return ItemAssets.Instance.AppleSprite;
         case ItemType.Bacon:
             return ItemAssets.Instance.BaconSprite;
         case ItemType.Bread:;
             return ItemAssets.Instance.BreadSprite;
         case ItemType.Fish:
             return ItemAssets.Instance.FishSprite;
         case ItemType.Steak:
             return ItemAssets.Instance.SteakSprite;
         case ItemType.Onion:
             return ItemAssets.Instance.OnionSprite;
    }
}
```

И данный класс со спрайтами тоже:

```
public class ItemAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ItemAssets Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {   
         Instance = this;
    }

    public Transform pfItemWorld;

    public Sprite AppleSprite;
    public Sprite BaconSprite;
    public Sprite BreadSprite;
    public Sprite FishSprite;
    public Sprite SteakSprite;
    public Sprite OnionSprite;

}
```

Comment: `С#` детище `Microsoft` и [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) у них качественная. В ней всегда есть примеры кода. Очень полезный ресурс, возьмите за привычку пользоваться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```csharp
public class ItemAssets : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ItemAssets Instance { get; private set; }

    private void Awake()
    {   
         Instance = this;
    }

    public Transform pfItemWorld;

    public Dictionary<string, Sprite> Sprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();   
}
```

Добавить или обновить элемент

```csharp
ItemAssets.Instance.Sprites["Apple"] = ...
```

Получить элемент

```csharp
Sprite apple = ItemAssets.Instance.Sprites["Apple"];
```

Как вы уже поняли, метод `GetSprite()` и энумератор `ItemType` - не нужны.